# How to solve the fopen error when use opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a simple code,but it confuse me one day

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

void example2_4(IplImage* image)
{

    cvNamedWindow("Example2_4-in", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("Example2_4-out", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cvShowImage("Example2_4-in", image);

    IplImage* out = cvCreateImage(
        cvGetSize(image),
        IPL_DEPTH_8U,
        3
    );

    cvSmooth(image, out, CV_GAUSSIAN, 5, 5);
    cvSmooth(out, out, CV_GAUSSIAN, 5, 5);

    cvShowImage("Example2_4-out", out);

    cvReleaseImage(&out);

    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example2_4-in");
    cvDestroyWindow("Example2_4-out");

}

int main()
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("lena.png");//This is my current image,you can use yourself's to test
    cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    example2_4(img);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
}
```

It always give a error information like the follow image

[image: image description]

1. Could I know which sentence call the "logger.h" file and result that
   error?
2. How to avoid such error?

Comment: That's because Microsoft wants you to use more secure version of fopen

Comment: I'll admit that this is quite unfair. Divide and conquer. Remove half of the code and recompile. If that particular error message is still present, this line is in the half you kept continue dividing the code in half. Else the line is in the other half start dividing the other half

Comment: However, your best bet, unless you want to re-write the library that's calling `fopen`, is to trust the folks who wrote the library and follow the suggestion on the latter half of the error message

Comment: You can #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS before #include "ConsoleApplicationLogger.h" to get around this compiler error

Comment: @Asesh Actually I have,but it doesn't work.That serve for you?

Comment: #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS before including stdafx.h then it should work. Just tried and it works

Comment: @Asesh Than I will get some [new errors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mPAVb.png)

Comment: Can't understand that language. But this is how it's done: #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "stdafx.h" then followed by inclusion of other header files

Comment: [That's means this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aGJPx.png).And [this configuration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jZCjO.png) will result a same error information..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151016/discussion-between-yode-and-asesh).

Comment: I think I need to specify,after I change the opencv from 2.4 to 3.2,everything works well.